# Does the card color matter for untapping it?

Tags: machi-koro

If a card is tapped (from the effect "on vacation"¹), its activation number has to be rolled to untap it.

**Does the card’s color matter here?** Does my **green/purple** card get untapped if my opponent rolls its number? Does my **red** card get untapped if I roll its number?

---

¹ I don’t know the English translation. In German it’s called "im Urlaub".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the English rules of Machi Koro Sharp either but the French version makes it clear (in a long paragraph just under the game components) that you need to roll the numbers needed to activate the building to untap it.

> Un établissement peut rouvrir lorsqu'il est à nouveau activé par le résultat des dés. [...] Donc les établissements bleus peuvent rouvrir pendant le tour de n'importe quel joueur, les établissements rouges uniquement pendant le tour des autres joueurs, tandis que les érablissements violets et verts peuvent rouvrir uniquement pendant votre tour.

which would translate by

> A building can re-open when it is activated by the result of a dice roll. [...] So blue buildings can re-open during any turn, red buildings can only re-open during the turn of an opponent and green or purple buildings can only re-open during the active player's turn.

Comment: Ah great, thank you. The German rules don’t state this (they only have the first sentence of your translation).

Comment: In fact,  he first sentence is enough I would say... The second one is only insisting on when you **activate** a building... Anyway, glad I could help, thanks for accepting the answer ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, for your translation that’s true, but the German one isn’t equivalent: It doesn’t say "activated", but more like: 'If the building’s number is rolled …'.

Comment: OK... That's not the same game this way ;-)